# Hosting your own NuGet and Symbol Source server?

Tags: nuget, remote-debugging, debug-symbols, nuget-package, nuget-server

I know that we can host our own private / internal NuGet server, but is there a way to also hosting your own Symbol Source server that links to your private NuGet packages? My company's policy doesn't allow publishing source code, even to SymbolSource.Org private repo.

Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the paid version of [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget), in addition to hosting your private NuGet feeds, includes a symbol/source server for those feeds.

Comment: As an update to this (almost two years later)... ProGet now includes Symbol Serving in the free edition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found out that SymbolSource released a community edition called [SymbolSource Server Basic](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-03-13/Releasing_the_community_edition_of_SymbolSource). Got it working in about an hour!

Comment: This does not appear to work with NuGet v3 client due to this truncating the 4th version decimal i.e. 1.0.0.0 becomes 1.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

this should be possible with NuGet.Server acting as a symbols+source server, according to this post: [NuGetsymbolssource-repository](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2012/02/26/NuRep-your-local-NuGetsymbolssource-repository)

let me know if that doesn't work,

Comment: I saw that while doing some research today. I'm not sure how active the project (NuRep) is though, seems like last commit/changes was back in February.

Comment: NuRep has changed its name to NuPeek (https://bitbucket.org/thinkbeforecoding/nupeek) and appears to be currently in active development.

Comment: Not so active any more

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity, as of version 7.x I believe, can be a NuGet server out-of-the-box.  And a symbol server with the addition of a plugin.  Here is the link to the plug-in: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Symbol+Server